# How do I get an element's index in an Array while iterating?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to add a method to the ruby class Array. Is it possible to reference the array and its indexes while iterating?

For example, I want to create a method to print elements of array along with their indexes.

```
array = [:a, :b, :c]

array.print_elements_with_indexes
# => a 1, b 2, c 3
```

Comment: `puts self.first` or `puts self[0]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland printing the first element is just an example. im not interested in a solution to that method. so if i want to refer to the array indexes i would use self?

Comment: the array is `self`. The value of the array at offset `i` is `self[i]`. To change the value of the array at offset `i`: `self[i] = 4`. To add `5` to the array `self << 5`. `self.delete_at(i)` to remove the element at offset `i`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are kinder than I with your cliff note Docs. OP `ruby` is by far one of the clearest and most extensively documented languages I have ever used. If you want to know something start with the documentation [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Array.html) for example.

Comment: @engineersmnky i use this ruby doc webpage all the time .. if you are telling me that i can find the class implementation details of Array on that page then i would love for you to show me otherwise i dont see where i would find this type of information.

Comment: First of all you are not in the class scope you are in an instance scope. Secondly the documents clearly tell you how to reference the index. Maybe take a look at `each_index`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self.<any-array-method>` and one such method is `size` using which you can create a range to iterate over each array elements.

```
class Array
  def do_something
    (0...self.size).each do |index|
        puts "Index #{index} value is #{self.at(index)}"
    end
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4].do_something
```

Or, you could use Ruby's `Enumerable#each_with_index` too as shown below:

```
class Array
  def do_something
    self.each_with_index do |index, value|
        puts "Index #{index} value is #{value}"
    end
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4].do_something
```

Comment: thanks this is the solution im looking for. i also figured it out outside of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def print_first
    puts first # same as `self.first`, or `self[0]`
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4].print_first # prints 1
```

If you're inside the scope of a class, defining an instance method, method calls will first resolve against `self`, which makes the `self.` optional in this case.

Comment: again im not interested in printing the first element, is it really that hard for the readers of the post to understand that ???????? im interested in REFERENCING THE ARRAY INDEXES .

Comment: It was indeed difficult to understand what you meant, as multiple people have misunderstood both your question and your example. After seeing the solution you were looking for, I'll edit your posted question to better match your actual question.